# How can I vertically align the numerators of two fractions?

Tags: equations, vertical-alignment, unicode-math

I am writing the following formula:

```
% arara: lualatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\begin{document}
\[y_\mathup{COG}=\frac{h}{3}\frac{l_\mathup{c,a}+2l_\mathup{c,i}}{l_\mathup{c,a}+l_\mathup{c,i}}\]
\end{document}
```

which yields:

[image]

I don't like the way, the `h` and `l_\mathup{index}` is vertically aligned. Is that typical behavior? Good style? Could I avoid that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can trick LaTeX into thinking the `h` had a subscript and thereby moving it upward to align with the `l`.

Alternatively, you can `\smash` the subscripts or the `l`s and thus lower them (this might look a bit cramped if you compare the space above and below the fraction bar).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\begin{document}
\begin{centering}
no modification
\[\enskip y_\mathup{COG}=\frac{h}{3}\frac{l_{\mathup{c,a}}+2l_\mathup{c,i}}{l_\mathup{c,a}+l_\mathup{c,i}}\]
\verb|\vphantom|
\[\enskip y_\mathup{COG}=\frac{h_{\vphantom{\mathup{c,a}}}}{3}\frac{l_{\mathup{c,a}}+2l_\mathup{c,i}}{l_\mathup{c,a}+l_\mathup{c,i}}\]
\verb|\smash|
\[\enskip y_\mathup{COG}=\frac{h}{3}\frac{l_{\smash{\mathup{c,a}}}+2l_{\smash{\mathup{c,i}}}}{l_{\smash{\mathup{c,a}}}+l_{\smash{\mathup{c,i}}}}\]
\end{centering}
\[\enskip y_\mathup{COG}=\frac{h}{3}\frac{l+2l}{l+l}\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

This behaviour seems to be caused by `unicode-math`, if compiled without that package the `h` and `l` are properly aligned without any modifications, indeed the modifications do not even seem to have an effect.

Comment: I wouldn't call this method a "trick". The `\vphantom` instruction was created on purpose to let users insert "struts" -- items that have height and/or depth but no width and hence are invisible -- to modify the heights and depths of the "boxes" that are TeX's most basic typeset items.

Comment: I mark this as an answer because it solves the problem. Thanks. The real answer, however, seems to be, that `unicode-math` has a bug. Without it, everything looks beautiful (like your `\vphantom` solution).

Comment: https://github.com/wspr/unicode-math/issues/259 says, it is not a bug. I've added the vphantoms now.

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not typical behavior or good style (to my taste, at least).  You won't have it, for instance, if you don't use the `mathtools` package:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\[y_{COG}=\frac{h}{3}\frac{l_{c,a}+2l_{c,i}}{l_{c,a}+l_{c,i}}\]
\end{document}
```

I don't have the package installed, so I cannot easily tell you if it's your doing or a bug.  One thing is certain, though, I think you need to add your `\mathup` subscripts in extra braces, like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\begin{document}
\[
  y_{\mathup{COG}} =
    \frac{h}{3}
    \frac{l_{\mathup{c,a}}+2l_{\mathup{c,i}}}
         {l_{\mathup{c,a}}+l_{\mathup{c,i}}}
\]
\end{document}
```

This could be the source of your problem.

Comment: Thank you. Actually the bug is in unicode-math. Mathtools works fine. I replaced unicode-math by amssymb and that works also. I will report that. Your second remark: the braces don't change anything. They are redundant.